# Async Await MVC Action returning Task instead of ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, elmah

I have an action as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Pair(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            DocuSignAPIManager docuSignAPIManager = new DocuSignAPIManager();

            DocuSignEsignatureAuthContainer authContainer = await docuSignAPIManager.Pair(User.Identity.Name, id).ConfigureAwait(false);

            DocuSignManager.Instance.Pair(User.Identity.Name, authContainer);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ErrorManager.Instance.LogError(e);
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
```

When the action is called all of the logic is executed, however instead of an HTTP Status 200 code, I receive the following:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
```

For testing I'm just calling the action from a web browser using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:20551/CharteredSurveyor/Pair/password
```

I really don't understand what the problem is - can anyone help?

Comment: I think this only works in MVC4 - are you definitely using version 4?

Comment: Dean, yes I'm definitely running MVC 4 - there's another action on a different controller with a similar signature - only real difference is that it accepts a FormCollection - really can't figure it out...

Comment: Does it work without async and tasks?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected without async and tasks

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4.5? If so, please upload a minimal repro gist (including csproj file).

Comment: Yes, I'm targeting .net 4.5.  I'm in the process of creating a gist - will post the URL asap

Comment: OK, I've stripped out a lot of code so that I just have the bare bones to make the above code compile.  When I run the code it works!  Still not working in the original project though...

Comment: Obviously some of the extra code causes the problem. Start adding parts of the original code until you encounter the error again

Comment: I've noticed something strange, the Pair method makes an await call on GetResponseAsync - when that is hit, code in my Action starts executing - is there an issue with multiple awaits?

Comment: OK, I've found the problem - just not sure what the solution is.  I followed http://www.benripley.com/development/net/asp-mvc-error-handling-with-elmah/ to add error handling.  When ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ErrorHandlingControllerFactory()) is commented out everything is fine - can anyone point me in the direction of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ErrorHandlingControllerFactory` from ELMAH returns a custom action invoker which it uses to make sure its `HandleErrorWithElmahAttribute` is applied to the controller. It never supplies an async action invoker so it doesn't understand async/await.

Two workarounds;

1. Try upgrading to the latest ELMAH - it may have fixes for async/await.
2. Remove the call to `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ErrorHandlingControllerFactory())` and simply add `HandleErrorWithElmahAttribute` to the global filters using `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorWithElmahAttribute());`

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: Dean, thanks for the feedback - I ended up going with option 2 - less code and the end result is the same (at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

changing

`public class authController : Controller`

to

`public class authController : AsyncController`

I made the controller class that contains the async action that gave that error inherit from AsyncController class instead of the default Controller class

I found that [answer here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1789174.aspx?async%20await%20Task%20JsonResutl%20produces%20System%20Threading%20Tasks%20Task%201%20System%20Web%20Mvc%20JsonResult%20over%20wire)